# video not autoplaying html

Tags: html, reactjs

hope you can clarify this issue:

I am trying to display few videos automatically on the website using video tags, however, sometimes the videos are not autoplaying and I can not find the reason why, does anyone has any clue about what can be the issue here?

```
  <Fade >
                <div className="portfolio__item">
                
                        <div className="portfolio__desc">
                            <video type="video/mp4" className="portfolio__img" autoPlay loop>
                                <source src={require("../../video/Hipstercoffe.mp4")}/>
                            </video>
                            <p>Website for a coffee shop.Simple project developed based on provided psd design.</p>
                            <p className="portfolio__stack">Tech stack: HTML, CSS, Sass, Bootstrap</p>
                            
                            <a className="portfolio__link" href="https://github.com/jgarnie/hipstercoffe" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><AiFillGithub size={32}/></a>
                            
                            
                        </div>
                    
                </div>
    </Fade>
```

Comment: `autoPlay` to `autoplay` change this.

Answer (score 0):

On the video, tage add controls before autoplay.

```
<video type="video/mp4" className="portfolio__img" controls autoplay loop>
   <source src={require("../../video/Hipstercoffe.mp4")}>
 </video>
```